# Include Typescript library in another Typescript library

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npm-install

I've a github typescript library which I'd like to install using

```
npm install --save git+ssh://git@github.com:User/mylib.git
```

in my target node service which is also in Typescript.

How do I get this done with type safety? I'd like to know if there are any type mismatches when I compile my service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what we used finally:

In the typescript library being exported (@myuser/lib1), we added the following line in `package.json`

"types": "./src/index.ts" or "./src/index.d.ts"

In the typescript service using the above library, we imported it as:

`npm install --save @myuser/lib1`

This installed the library with types and compiles your service with type safety checks.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know if there are any type mismatches when I compile my service.

Make sure your library has :

- `tsconfig.json` : `outDir` and `declaration:true`
- `typings` pointing to the outDir

## Example

TypeStyle ships with TypeScript definitions : https://github.com/typestyle/typestyle